# please let me know why i get this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'top_performer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Here I have my Python code code, I don't understand why I am getting the following error. Any guidance or help would be much appreciated.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'top_performer' referenced before assignment

def create(X, y, **kwargs):

```
method = kwargs.get("method", None)
#method = kwargs.get("method", "Binary_operators")
#method = kwargs.get("method", "Binning")
#method = kwargs.pop("method", "Cluster")
#categorical_cols = [c for c, t in zip(X.columns, X_column_types) if t in [DATATYPE_CATEGORY_INT, DATATYPE_CATEGORY_STRING]]
#numerical_cols = [c for c, t in zip(X.columns, X_column_types) if t == DATATYPE_NUMBER]
#categorical = X[categorical_cols]
#numerical = X[numerical_cols]
categorical = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])
numerical = X.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
# feature selection using Genetic Algorithm
if method == "fs_GA":
    print("fs_GA")
    enc = OneHotEncoder()
    enc.fit(categorical)
    Data_cat=pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(categorical).toarray())
    X_data = pd.concat([numerical, Data_cat], axis=1)

    if y.dtype == int:
        y = y
    else:
        from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
        le = LabelEncoder()
        le.fit(y)
        y = le.transform(y)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)

    def get_fitness(individual):
        if y.dtype == int:
            rg = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
        else:
            rg = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)

        columns = [column for (column, binary_value) in zip(X_train.columns, individual) if binary_value]
        training_set = X_train[columns]
        test_set = X_test[columns]
        rg.fit(training_set.values, y_train)
        preds = rg.predict(test_set.values)
        return 100 / np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, preds))

    individual = [1] * 100
    get_fitness(individual)

    def get_population_fitness(population):
        return sorted([(individual, get_fitness(individual)) for individual in population], key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)

    def crossover(individual_a, individual_b):
        crossing_point = random.randint(0, 99)
        offspring_a = individual_a[0:crossing_point] + individual_b[crossing_point:100]
        offspring_b = individual_b[0:crossing_point] + individual_a[crossing_point:100]
        return offspring_a, offspring_b

    def tournament(current_population):
        index = sorted(random.sample(range(0, 20), 5))
        tournament_members  = [current_population[i] for i in index]
        total_fitness = sum([individual[1] for individual in tournament_members])
        probabilities = [individual[1] / total_fitness for individual in tournament_members]
        index_a, index_b = np.random.choice(5, size=2, p=probabilities)
        return crossover(tournament_members[index_a][0], tournament_members[index_b][0])

    def mutation(individual):
        mutation_point = random.randint(0, 99)
        if(individual[mutation_point]):
            individual[mutation_point] = 0
        else:
            individual[mutation_point] = 1

    def build_next_generation(current_population, mutation_rate):
        next_generation = []
        next_generation.append(current_population[0][0]) # elitism
        next_generation.append(current_population[random.randint(1,19)][0]) # randomness

        for i in range(9): # tournaments
            offspring_a, offspring_b = tournament(current_population)
            next_generation.append(offspring_a)
            next_generation.append(offspring_b)

        for individual in next_generation: # mutation
            if(random.randint(1,mutation_rate) == 1):
                mutation(individual)
        return next_generation


    def run_ga(current_population, num_of_generations, mutation_rate=1000):
        fittest_individuals = []

        for i in range(num_of_generations):
            current_population = get_population_fitness(current_population) # get pop fitness
            fittest_individuals.append(current_population[0]) # record fittest individual (for graphing and analysis)
            current_population = build_next_generation(current_population, mutation_rate) # make new population
            return fittest_individuals


    initial_population = [[random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(100)] for i in range(20)]
    high_mutation_fittest = run_ga(initial_population, 100, mutation_rate=5)



    high_mutation_fitness = [ind[1] for ind in high_mutation_fittest]
    for item in high_mutation_fittest[:-1]:
        if item[1] == max(high_mutation_fitness):
            top_performer = item
            break
    print("Total features included: " + str(top_performer[0].count(1)))

    selected_features = [column for (column, binary_value) in zip(X.columns, top_performer[0]) if binary_value]
    excluded_features = [column for (column, binary_value) in zip(X.columns, top_performer[0]) if not binary_value]
    X = X[selected_features]


if method == "Binary_operators":
    print("binaryoperators")

if method == "Binning":
    print("binning")

else:
    print("Discretization")

if method == "Cluster":
    print("clustering")
else:
    print("no-cluster")

print("normal_autocross")
```

So when I run the code I get the following error and I don't seem to understand what it means. Can someone please explain to me why i'm getting this error?

```
create(X, y, method="fs_GA")
```

fs_GA

---

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 create(X, y, method="fs_GA")

in create(X, y, **kwargs)
    107                 top_performer = item
    108                 break
--> 109         print("Total features included: " + str(top_performer[0].count(1)))
    110 
    111         selected_features = [column for (column, binary_value) in zip(X.columns, top_performer[0]) if binary_value]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'top_performer' referenced before assignment

Comment: Sorry i found the mistake in code and it has solved. Thank you who invested the time

Answer (score 1):

```
top_performer = 0
for item in high_mutation_fittest[:-1]:
    if item[1] == max(high_mutation_fitness):
        top_performer = item
        break
print("Total features included: " + str(top_performer[0].count(1)))
```

According to your code top_performer is an int variable, not an array, `str(top_performer)` is correct way of using it. `str(top_performer).count('1')` , this could be what you are looking for. ***count*** is for string not int